# PATH in shell getting mysterious entry (fish shell, ubuntu system)

Tags: fish

I am using fish shell on a Ubuntu sytem. This question is about redundancy in `$PATH` that I am setting unintentionally.

When I type `echo $PATH`, I get:

> /opt/anaconda3/bin/ /opt/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/ /opt/anaconda3/bin/ /opt/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/ /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games .

Multiple annoyances with this: */opt/anaconda3/bin* showing up twice, showing some non-existant directories: */usr/local/games /usr/games*.

My */etc/login.defs* reads:

```
ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

So the redundancy is not coming from there.  Of course, my *PATH* in *config.fish* is set as:

```
set -gx PATH /opt/anaconda3/bin/ (/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda info --root)/etc/fish/conf.d/ $PATH .
```

My Question: where does fish get its *PATH* from, other than what is set in my environment and what is handed to it by: */etc/login.defs*?

UPDATE: I changed to using fish_user_paths variable, per documentation which got rid of /opt/anaconda3/bin added twice.  Still the /usr/games/ and /usr/local/games are getting added automagically (and those directories don't exist on my system!).

Comment: PATH can also be modified in `.bashrc` or equivalent depending on the used SHELL

Comment: My apologies. This is with fish shell.  I just selected that tag originally but did not explicitly add that in the posting.  Question updated now to reflect that this is related to fish shell.

Comment: sorry I didn't know fish is a shell. What is the result of `/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda info --root` done by hand ?

Comment: /opt/anaconda3/bin/conda info --root just returns the string "/opt/anaconda3/". (Yes, it is needed - though looks redundant.)

Comment: Note my  /etc/login.defs sets _PATH_ to `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` (raspbian on raspberrypi)

Comment: perhaps some other settings are made through additional files (sometimes there is a `.login` in the home dir) perhaps do `echo tag $PATH >>/tmp/aze` or equivalent on some places in `/etc/login.defs` and `.bashrc` changing _tag_ to trace where the changes are done and look at `/tmp/aze` after you logout - login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around on the Internet, this is not a shell related issue: fish shell or any other shell.  It's a Linux issue.  The kernel, somewhere before forking the init, reads the:
/etc/environment file and sets the system wide default path.

In a single user environment, we could just edit that file - if we insist. Personally, I added lines to my fish profile to purge the non-existant directories from the path :

`if set -l index (contains -i -- /usr/local/games $PATH)
    set --erase PATH[$index]
end
if set -l index (contains -i -- /usr/games $PATH)
    set --erase PATH[$index]
end`